# What I do to call An Activity from My CCScene in Cocos2d?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

**From Activity to CCScene , we implement this code :**

```
 CCScene scene = Class_name.scene();
 CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);
```

But From CCScene to Call the Activity , What Should I use ?

**If it is Possible than suggest me to implement this thing.**

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
     CCDirector.theApp.startActivity(activity);
```

This is the way to all an activity